# Can't get custom user from everyauth

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, everyauth

I did read manuals about access to current user via everyauth. It's say, that I can read current user info from: **req.user** on my server, **everyauth.user** and **user** on my views, but they are undefined. But if I'm try get access from, for example, everyauth.twitter or everyauth.facebook, I'm get user info from this social networks.

I'm want, when get user from database (find or create by social data) it's must save in session variable, like **currentUser**, and i can get it in helpers and in other databare requests.

My app.js code:

```
var express     = require('express')
  , everyauth   = require('everyauth')
  , Promise     = everyauth.Promise
  , util        = require('util')
  , mongoose    = require('mongoose')
  , routes      = require('./routes')
  , _           = require('underscore')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/base');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

// Everyauth settings above that app.configure

everyauth.twitter
  .consumerKey('secretKey')
  .consumerSecret('secret')
  .findOrCreateUser(function (session, accessToken, accessTokenSecret, twitterUserData){
      var promise = this.Promise();
      User.findOrCreateByUidAndNetwork(twitterUserData.id, 'twitter', twitterUserData, promise);
      return promise;
  })
  .redirectPath('/')
everyauth.facebook
    .appId("secretId")
    .appSecret("secret")
    .findOrCreateUser( function (session, accessToken, accessTokenExtra, fbUserMetadata) {
      var promise = this.Promise();
      User.findOrCreateByUidAndNetwork(fbUserMetadata.id, 'facebook', fbUserMetadata, promise);
      return promise;
    })
    .redirectPath('/');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({secret:'blablabla'}));
  app.use(everyauth.middleware()); // Yes, i'm use it
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router); // And it
  app.use(express['static'](__dirname + '/public'));
});

everyauth.helpExpress(app); // And this above that routes

app.dynamicHelpers({
    currentUser: function (req, res){
        return req.user; //it's empty!
    }
})

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);
require("./controllers/user");

app.listen(80);
```

And user Scheme:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    "uid":{type:String},    
    "name":{type:String},   
    "network":{type:String},
    "profile":{}        
});


mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

And user find or create function:

```
this.findOrCreateByUidAndNetwork = function(uid, network, profile, promise) {
    User.find({uid: uid, network: network}, function(err, users) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(users.length > 0) {
            promise.fulfill(users[0]);// <-- what i want:)
        } else {
            var user = new User();
            user.network = network;
            user.uid = uid;
            user.profile = profile;
            user.name = profile.first_name || profile.name;
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                promise.fulfill(user);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Thanks, for watching my question. Best regards, Asci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly a little late, but for anyone who needs an answer to this -

On Everyauth's Github page it specifies that "To access the user, configure everyauth.everymodule.findUserById". So for example (again quoting bnoguchi) -

```
everyauth.everymodule
    .findUserById( function (id, callback) {
        yourApi.fetchUserById(id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, user);
     });
     // or more succinctly, if your api sends a user to the callback with function signature function (err, user):
     // yourApi.fetchUserById(id, callback);
});
```